# Jquery/Javascript: what does the " i " in " (function(i){ " do/mean? How does it know that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

In the example below, the Jquery code changes the src of the images on the page to start with `"test"`, and end with `".jpg"`, but what tells it what `i` is? if i'm correct, `i` could also be `number`, or `e`, or `z`, or `n`, or whatever word or letter i want, so, by placing that `i` in there, is it saying that `i` is the current object? or the name of the object? or is it just a variable, and if it's a variable, what tells it what the variable holds? what is `i`? is it a number? and if I were to change the `i` to an `h`, would that be the same?

```
$("img").each(function(i){ 
  this.src = "test" + i + ".jpg"; 
});
HTML:
<img/><img/>
Result:
<img src="test0.jpg"/><img src="test1.jpg"/>
```

anyone know any good tutorials that would address this specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is the **index** of the element in the set of elements that `$("img")` found.

You can find the callback parameters documented in [the `.each()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

> **.each( function(index, Element) )**
>   function(index, Element) - A function to execute for each matched element.

As for changing it, yes you can call the parameter anything you want (as long as it's not a keyword) and use that same name in the function.

Comment: Technically, `i` is a *parameter*, which jQuery's `each` function will supply with the index of the current element.

Comment: Yes (although that was not how I interpreted the title) — but it's still important to note that it is a parameter, not an index as such. There's a lot of misused terms in the jQuery world, IMHO.

Comment: so if it was a click, what would the i be? what would it hold? or? eg: $("img").click(function(i){

Comment: @android - for event handlers like `.click()` (*all* jQuery event handlers), that first parameter is the jQuery event object: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ you usually would name that parameter accordingly, `e` or `event`.

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery .each docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/) covers this, though they could be more clear. The key line is "Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0." That's the `i` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the variable name from i to any other name will have no effect on what the variable's type is. In this case, it's an integer.